# JS How to update list items

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to update the second list based on the item clicked in the first list :
[image]

So what I'm doing is that I launch a function on the `onclick` property of the links of the first list that does the request and add new elements.
The problem is that every time I click on a different element, the new ones are added to the old ones instead of replacing them, which is normal 'cause I used `createElement`.

So I tried to delete the old ones before loading the new ones (commented code) but it did not work :/

```js
function catalogRequest(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){this.readyState, status, this.responseText};
    http.open('GET', 'http://localhost:31000/catalog');
    http.send();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            loadCatalog(this.responseText);
        }
    };

}


function loadCatalog(categoriesText){
    let categories = JSON.parse(categoriesText);
    console.log(categories);
    categories.forEach(element => {
        let panel = document.getElementById('catalog');
        let panelLink = document.createElement('a');
        panelLink.className = 'panel-block';
        panelLink.onclick = function(){ categoryRequest(element['id']);};
        panelLink.text = element['name'];
        panel.appendChild(panelLink);  
    });    
}

function categoryRequest(id){
    // Remove the old links before loading the new ones
    // let oldLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('category-link');
    // console.log(oldLinks);
    // for(let item of oldLinks){
    //     document.removeChild(item);
    // }
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){this.readyState, status, this.responseText};
    http.open('GET', 'http://localhost:32000/list?id=' + id);
    http.send();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            loadCategories(this.responseText);
        }
    };
}

function loadCategories(productsText){
    let products = JSON.parse(productsText);
    console.log(products);
    products.forEach(element => {


        let panel = document.getElementById('category');
        let panelLink = document.createElement('a');
        panelLink.className = 'panel-block category-link';
        panelLink.onclick = categoryRequest(element['id']);
        panelLink.text = element['name'];
        panel.appendChild(panelLink);  
    });    
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <nav class="panel is-primary" id="catalog">
         <p class="panel-heading">Catalog</p>
     </nav>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <nav class="panel is-info" id="category">
         <p class="panel-heading">Category</p>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: `item` is not a direct child of `document`. Either call `item.remove()` or simply `.innerHTML = ""` on the category panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

empty categories list before insert:

```
function loadCategories(productsText){
    let products = JSON.parse(productsText);
    console.log(products);
    let panel = document.getElementById('category');
    panel.innerHTML = "";
    products.forEach(element => {
        let panelLink = document.createElement('a');
        panelLink.className = 'panel-block category-link';
        panelLink.onclick = categoryRequest(element['id']);
        panelLink.text = element['name'];
        panel.appendChild(panelLink);  
    });    
}
```

Comment: replace `panel.innerHTML = "";` with `panel.innerHTML = "<p class='panel-heading'>Category</p>"`